# My CTE seems properly written but I am receiving an error. What is wrong it with?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to learn common table expressions and I don't understand why I get this error.

I want to get the first name of the employee and their project titles, for all employees whose salary is greater than half of the maximum salary.

These are the tables:

[image]

And this is the code I use

```
with cte1 as (
  select max(salary) as ms from employees
)
select e.first_name, p.title
from employees e
join employees_projects ep on ep.employee_id = e.id
join projects p on p.id = ep.project_id
where  e.salary > (cte1.ms) / 2
```

What I'm trying to do is learn CTEs, so what I need to know is what is wrong with what I'm doing with the CTE, why do I get an error?

The error is

> ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 21: Unknown column 'cte1.m' in 'where clause'

Thanks!

Comment: You're not referencing the CTE in your select statement. You probably want to cross join to it...

Comment: CTE is excess in this particular case - use subquery in WHERE.